# QPython3 on Android read and write txt file

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, qpython, qpython3

I am writing a little python textbased game on my android phone with qpython3.
Now I want to store the highscores in a txt file but I can't find out how I can realize this. I know how I can do it on windows but it doesn't work on android.

Hope anyone has an idea.

Krowit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing on my device, it appears that QPython has blocked write permissions from the application. Here's a way of getting a version which allows for it*:

1. Download SL4A, and install it. This is what launches the Python script.
2. Download PY4A, this is the Android version of Python. You can download both 2.x and 3.x from [here](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/list).
3. You'll need a text editor now. DroidEdit is my personal favourite, and you can launch a script straight from the app.
4. Then you can write in your code, save it, and run it!

Of course, there's no real substitute for a real desktop, at least in my opinion, but this is (again, in my opinion) the best setup I've found so far.

*I don't know where the files are saved, but you can read and write from them, wherever the saved file's directory may be.